# Does putting an "and" between two verbs alter qualifying clauses?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, imperatives

In the following .. does the 'date clause' apply to one, the other, or both imperatives.

"To confirm your miles balance, just purchase and fly with "airline" or the Partner Airlines to any destination and for any fare, between 25 May and 24 June 2017."

And what is the grammatical reason for which it is..?

I believe it was translated from Italian (we would say May 24th in USA) as this is an Italian airline (name of airline intentionally omitted).

Below is the entire context:

> According to the terms and conditions, when no new miles have been
>   earned under the Program over a period of 24 months, the miles in the
>   account expire and are cancelled.
>
> But you are still in time to save them!
>
> To confirm your miles balance, just purchase and fly with "airline" or
>   the Partner Airlines to any destination and for any fare, between 25
>   May and 24 June 2017.

Comment: I think the question may better phrased are purchase .. and fly between .. two separate clauses. If so..  Does the command in the second phrase affect that first verb (purchase)

Comment: Paige: I think this is what you are asking; whether the 'date clause' applies to one, the other,  or both  imperatives. If not, feel free to re-edit.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  Yes does purchasing have to happen between those dates or only the actual travel.   Guessing it has something to do with whether it is two separate imperative clauses or two coordinate predicates.   The question isn't whether it was well written or not.. the question is what does it's grammatical being require

Comment: Are the requirements (according the way it is in its present phrasing) meant to intend two requirements 1) just purchase 2) fly between /two implied subjects

Comment: Clearly the real requirement is that you fly before 24 June.  And we know that airlines let you purchase early so if you happened to have purchased your tickets prior to 25 May it wouldn’t be a problem for them.  My guess is that 25 May is around the time they sent this notice and so unless you already had your tickets it would be impossible to purchase prior to that.

Comment: What does "alter qualifying clauses" mean?

Comment: Contact the airline and ask for the full terms and conditions (they may be available on their website). That is the way you'll answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

This passage does not seem to be optimally translated. To "confirm" your balance is to verify the amount in it. What they seem to mean is to "maintain" or "keep" your balance.

The verb "purchase" lacks an object. Standard English is "book a flight with" rather than "purchase and fly with." "Book any flight with" would eliminate the need for the cumbersome "to any destination and for any fare."

There still remains some ambiguity. Is it the purchase or the flight that has to take place between the dates mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly grammatical Bureaucratic English, but like most such sentences, it's been excessively massaged to get all those pesky Terms and Conditions loaded. If you put back all the repetitive stuff that's been removed, the original sentence might be something like this

- *In order for you to confirm the  balance of your miles, you must purchase a ticket from "airline" to any destination for any fare between 25 May and 24 June 2017, **or** you must purchase a ticket from the Partner Airlines to any destination for any fare between 25 May and 24 June 2017, **and** you must fly with "airline" on that ticket between 25 May and 24 June 2017, **or** you must fly with the Partner Airlines on that ticket between 25 May and 24 June 2017.*

The *and*s and *or*s are emboldened to show how the conjunctions work:  [(X₁ **or** X₂) **and** (Y₁ **or** Y₂)]

- You must do an X **and** you must do a Y  (no choice)

  - You may do X₁ **or** you may do X₂ (you must choose one)
  - You may do Y₁ **or** you may do Y₂ (you must choose one)

Comment: The American Chinese Menu Principle: One from column A and one from column B.

Answer (score 0):

With the adverbial phrase 'between ...' positioned outside of the coordination 'purchase and fly', it applies to both.

Comment: But since it has an imperative and a declarative clause would it not make it an asymmetric construction?

Comment: There is no declarative clause:  (adverbial: To infinite predicate), just coordinated imperatives (adverbial PP: with coordinated NPs) (adverbial coordinated PPs: to NP and for NP) (adverbial PP: between coordinated NPs).  Note: I would include a comma before 'to any' to make it clear that the destination and fare apply to both choices of airline.